# changing project name in visual studio team foundation suite

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

ON tfs 2010 once i create a project i want to be able to change the name with out having to create a new project and copying over all the files? Any Idea??

Answer (score 0):

Allied website serverfault provides your answer: [link text](https://serverfault.com/questions/7686/how-to-rename-a-project-in-the-team-foundation-server-tfs)
No go i am afraid, except copying over the files (and workitems, builddefinitions etc)